# Kinetic.js slow on Firefox

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a smooth animation using Kinetic.js in Firefox.  It looks great in Chrome and Safari, and even looks more-or-less okay in IE9, but Firefox is jerky.  I tried using both the built-in Kinetic.Animate, and requestAnimationFrame, and both ended up looking the same.  Any ideas?

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 1000,
      height: 1000
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var blackRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 700,
      y: 650,
      width: 300,
      height: 620,
      fill: "black",
      offset: [150, 620]
    });

    var colorRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 300,
      y: 650,
      width: 300,
      height: 620,
      fill: "blue",
      offset: [150, 620]
    });

    layer.add(blackRect);
    layer.add(colorRect);
    stage.add(layer);

    function oscillate(node, time) {
      var period = 5400;
      var phase = 1200;
      var amplitude = 1.2;
      var shift = amplitude * Math.cos(phase + time * 2 * Math.PI / period);
      node.setPosition(node.getX() + shift, node.getY());
    }

    function rotate(node, time) {
      var period = 5400;
      var amplitude = 0.08;
      node.setRotation((amplitude * Math.sin(time * 2 * Math.PI / period) ));
    }

    function render(time) {

      layer.draw();
    }


    var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function (frame) {
      oscillate(blackRect, frame.time);
      oscillate(colorRect, frame.time);

      rotate(blackRect, frame.time);
      rotate(colorRect, frame.time);
    }, layer);

    anim.start();
});
</script>
```

Edit:
Here is the above example: http://jsfiddle.net/cantino/yr8Zr/

Comment: could you provide a link to live implementation to understand what you mean, or still better a fiddle where we can also edit and test

Comment: Sure Ani, here's a link to the above code on jsfiddle.  You should try it in Chrome and FF.  http://jsfiddle.net/cantino/yr8Zr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, FF currently produces less-smooth animations.

You can get smoother-but-slower animation results by:

- Using frame.timeDiff to throttle the frames-per-second,
- And reducing your amplitude.

If smoother-but-slower breaks your design you can use the custom Kinetic.Shape to get "closer to the metal".

With Kinetic.Shape, you get a canvas context to draw on instead of relying on the easier (but less performant) Kinetic.Rect.

Comment: Thanks markE!  How significant is the performance difference between Kinetic.Shape and Kinetic.Rect?

Comment: It's faster (because there's less overhead than fully managed objects like rect).

Comment: I should have mentioned it earlier, but if you don't need events on your rects, you can stop listening for events on them.  That makes a big difference in performance, too.  (In your rect definition, add "listening:false").

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question was answered long time ago, but i encountered this issue recently too, and the answers provided here gave only a marginal performance boost. 
So i looked into the core of KineticJS and found a fix that got my FPS from 10 to almost 60. Some times the FPS dropped as low as 2.

The fix is for those who may encounter this issue in the future and search for an answer.

```
stage._mousemove = Kinetic.Util._throttle( stage._mousemove, 60);
someKineticLayer._getIntersection = function() {return {};};

//keep in mind that tampering with _getIntersection will disable mouse interaction for that layer and may have other effects.
```